# Verify statement regarding Lightning/JavaScript from developer?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

One of our developers just emailed our team with the following statement.  I'm not familiar enough with Lightning Developer to determine if the statement is entirely accurate.

> With our orgs now supporting lightning and hopefully more BU’s getting
>   lightning in the future, we will probably need some custom Lightning
>   pages that need code. The hardest and most time consuming part of
>   lightning apps are UI and UX development. Salesforce has given the
>   Lightning Design System which gives you templates to make your page
>   look native. The problem is that they don’t provide any javascript to
>   make things like tables interactive and user friendly. We would have
>   to develop that code ourselves which pretty much triples the time of
>   the project to get something working just OK. Check out the
>   lightningstrike website link below. The site provides a javascript
>   framework that hooks up with the Lightning Design System. Lots of cool
>   UI that we could easily plug and play into any custom app in the
>   future. This could also allow us to create POC’s much easier and make
>   lightning pages immediately mobile friendly.

Comment: To my opinion, that was right until Winter18'. There will be 20 new cool components with native Javascript for user interaction.

Comment: The "triples the time of the project" seems inflated. They are also using VF using SLDS and Lightning Components as interchangeable when they are two separate development items . the VF with SLDS is true, no JS, just CSS. For Lightning component, many of the components do what is intended. As always some custom code may be required to get it looking just like you want it. After working with lightning, it does not increase the time to develop but it also does not really decrease it cause there are all sorts of neat thing you can now do that you include lol

Comment: There really is a lot of assumptions and opinions in both this question and the answers. Bottom line, all things considered, cost to develop a Lightning component vs the same thing in VF IMHO - VF would take me longer now with the current state of lightning. Interested to see what the community thinks in an actual answer

Comment: Another opinion: native Lightning development takes longer today (yep I agree with x3) for several reasons: 1) takes developers time learn it; 2) SF provided component set has been immature/incomplete; 3) not much good 3rd party stuff; 4) JavaScript libraries that contain cool stuff often can't be used; 5) testing framework coming but not GA yet; 6) more interactive UI is more complicated so takes more time to build. The story will hopefully be different in a few years time but there is early adopter pain still today. lightningstrike.io might help - depends on the specifics of what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The hardest and most time consuming part of lightning apps are UI and UX development.

I would agree with this. There's a lot of elements to learn, a lot of CSS to learn, and generally speaking, even if you know the CSS pretty well, you're going to be using the documentation to build any non-trivial element. The CSS is becoming less significant for native lightning apps and components as we are introduced to new built-in components (like the 20'ish new ones coming out in the next release).

Two years ago or so, developing in Lightning was basically 99% pure HTML and CSS, while now it's more like 30% HTML/CSS and 70% components. As we continue to build new components, and have new ones given to us, we will eventually approach 0% HTML/CSS for most normal situations, similar to how Visualforce is today; we will be able to write Lightning-looking apps without needing to resort to the Lightning Design System guide every time we want to build an app. This will eventually make developing in Lightning at least as fast as Visualforce, particularly since most tasks that can be built in Visualforce require less code in Lightning.

> The problem is that they don’t provide any javascript to make things like tables interactive and user friendly.

This is true; you're expected to write your own scripts. However, most scripts are very trivial to write. I wrote a pagination and sortable table in less than 60 lines of Lightning JavaScript without any libraries. And realistically, we can (and should) develop our own Lightning components so that we don't have to reinvent the wheel each time we want to do something. Or maybe we'll eventually be given more components that have built-in behavior like sorting, pagination, drag-and-drop, etc.

> We would have to develop that code ourselves which pretty much triples the time of the project to get something working just OK.

This is true for a developer that is still learning Lightning and JavaScript, because the entire system is unfamiliar. However, I wrote my pagination/sorting demo in less time, and in less code, than I would have used in Visualforce, and I've been writing in Visualforce since before the dawn of Visualforce (I was in the beta program).

I've also learned the basics of Lightning in far less time than it took me to learn Visualforce, mostly because JavaScript is one of my most familiar languages, aside from Apex Code. Lightning makes difficult chores easier, and easy chores trivial. One simply needs to learn how it works. It's new, it's different, but it's definitely not "hard".

> Check out the lightningstrike website link below. The site provides a javascript framework that hooks up with the Lightning Design System. Lots of cool UI that we could easily plug and play into any custom app in the future.

Strike is a framework of components, which provides a library of new features. Any decent library will indeed decrease development time in the long run, which is the purpose of Strike. However, if your developers are struggling to write Lightning code, Strike may very well *harm* their performance as developers, because they will have new stuff to learn atop Lightning.

A lot of developers think that libraries are a magic bullet to improving development speed, but that's only true if they already have a firm grasp of the basic system. They should not be trying to learn Strike if they still don't understand Lightning very well. I can tell you that, to date, I have never used a library in Lightning, not jQuery, nor Angular, nor anything else. I have, however, used almost every component in the library, because that's the point of components. Components are reusable elements, and we should have a large library of them in order to consistently reduce development time.

> This could also allow us to create POC’s much easier and make lightning pages immediately mobile friendly.

Lightning is already mobile-friendly without much effort. Many of the components I have written run just fine on my phone, and I did't even *consider* writing a mobile version of the component. If the developers don't understand Lightning, then Strike will not be of any immediate use to them. Strike isn't a magic bullet. There is no shortcut to writing good Lightning code.

If they understand Lightning well enough that they *could* write most of the Strike components by hand, then they're ready to use Strike. If they could not do so, then Strike won't help them learn Lightning. They might be able to use it, but their code won't perform as well as one that understands Lightning. Strike is an invaluable tool for developers that can use it, but won't help someone learn Lightning.